# Win7 hostednetwork not visible although it's started

Tags: windows-7, wifi-configuration

As the title says I don't have a problem like many other people where I can't start the hostednetwork. I can actually start it and it has worked perfectly until several days ago. And since then I'm unable to see it with any device.

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

is successful and I can see the network in windows.

But the problem is when I call the command

```
netsh wlan show hostednetwork
```

then I get the error "The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation."
When it worked correctly then it said that it was started and it showed number of clients connected.
And when it is stopped "show command" works and it correctly says that it is "Not started".

Someone please help because none of the standard fixes like disable/enable of the adapters or reinstalling drivers work.

Comment: Duplicate of [netsh hostednetwork issue](http://superuser.com/q/539438)

Comment: Thank you for linking the duplicate issue. For some reason I couldn't find it neither here or via Google. But in any case it seems that in the other thread solution unfortunately hasn't been found.

Comment: Just an update on this issue. It seems that it works correctly when I'm not present in my companies domain. I went home, logged in with my domain account, but since I was connected to my wireless network everything was working correctly.  
So I tried PCs of other colleagues, but they work properly although they are also in domain and they can create the hotspot.